# WIN32API: owner-drawn button creates white background around the text when clicked

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, user-interface

I have created an Owner-Drawn button . I use the WM_CTLCOLORBTN message in order to paint it :

```
//get the text of the button
         wchar_t buttonText[20]; 
         int textLength = SendMessage((HWND)lParam,WM_GETTEXT,20,(LPARAM)buttonText);

         Font FootlightMTLight(L"Footlight MT Light",20,0,false,false,false,L"Black");
         SelectObject((HDC)wParam,FootlightMTLight.getWindowHandle());

         TextOut((HDC)wParam,30,15,buttonText,textLength);
         SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0,0,0));
         SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(229,255,229));

         PatBlt((HDC)wParam,0,0,1,50,BLACKNESS); //x,y,width,height
         PatBlt((HDC)wParam,269/2-1,0,1,50,BLACKNESS);
         PatBlt((HDC)wParam,0,49,269/2,1,BLACKNESS);
         PatBlt((HDC)wParam,0,0,269/2,1,BLACKNESS);

        static HBRUSH handleToButtonBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(229,255,229));
        return (INT_PTR)handleToButtonBrush;
```

"Font" is an object I created (I wrapped HFONT handle and CreateFont function with class etc. getWindowHandle() basically returns HFONT ).

the button renders nicely , yet pressing on it make the text-background turn white. 
I search the net for a reason and a solution yet I didn't find a concrete one.
thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call those lines before the actual text drawing occurs

```
SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(0,0,0));
SetBkColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(229,255,229));
TextOut((HDC)wParam,30,15,buttonText,textLength);
```

Comment: Or `SetBkMode` to transparent so you don't have to remember what the background color is.